# Excel VBA range select

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in which I need to select the range `R2:last row in sheet`. However the last row in my sheet might be blank in column `R`. At the moment I am using this

```
Dim t As Range
Set t = Range("R2", Range("R1000").End(xlUp))

For Each Cell In t
    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        Cell.Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = "To Be Picked Up"
    End If
Next
```

However if the last row has a blank in column `R` then it gets ignored. I am hoping to pull the range using column `A`, as the last row of data always has column `A`. So something like,

```
Dim t As Range
Set t = Range("R2", Range("A1000").End(xlUp).ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17))

For Each Cell In t
    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        Cell.Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = "To Be Picked Up"
    End If
Next
```

It seems so simple but I'm sure im missing something stupid. Any help or alternative methods would be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick in one line:

```
Sub SO()     
    Range("R2:R" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "To Be Picked Up"
End Sub
```

---

But in answer to your question *specifically*

```
Set t = Range("R2:R" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

The `Range()` method will accept a string as an argument to obtain a range.So we can build this string any way we want:

```
"A1000"                '// A1000
"A" & 1000             '// A1000
"A" & "10" & "00"      '// A1000
"A" & CStr(1001 - 1)   '// A1000
```

- `"A" & Rows.Count` will return `A65536` or `A1048576` depending on the type of worksheet.
- `Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)` as you know, will retrieve the last cell in that area, or the first cell in the next area on the direction specified.
- `Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row` will return the row number of that cell *(let's say it's A1000 for argument's sake)* so the return value is `1000`.
- `"R2:R" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` therefore makes the string `R2:R1000`.
- So finally, `Range("R2:R" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` is the same as `Range("R2:R1000")`